# Selecting a radio button when clicking an image

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I want to select radio button when I click on his image but it's not working.
This is what I've tried:

```
<ul id="options-31-list" class="options-list">
    <li>
        <a class="mydata" href="" data="84">
            <img class="small-image-preview" src="value_id/84/file/o2.jpg/">
        </a>
        <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" type="radio" data="84" value="84" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice();">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="mydata" href="" data="85">
            <img class="small-image-preview" src="value_id/85/file/vodafone.jpg/">
        </a>
        <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" type="radio" data="85" value="85" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice();">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="mydata" href="" data="86">
            <img class="small-image-preview" src="value_id/86/file/t-mobile.jpg/">
        </a>
        <input class="radio validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" type="radio" data="86" value="86" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice();">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the same **data=""** attribute for both: for image and for input, is there any way to make the input (that radio) to be checked when I click on image?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
I found some code that work, but only for three clicks on image, so when click to the last one the script is stop, can't select the first or second again, I don't know why... I think must to uncheck all radio buttons and than check the one selected ... 
can someone help me with this?

```
jQuery(".mydata").click(function(){ 
jQuery(this).parent().children("input").attr('checked','true');              
})
```

Comment: do you need the `onClick`-function to be triggered when the radio-button is selected via the click on the img?

Comment: Your php `getOptionTypeId` returns 0?

Comment: yes getOptionTypeId returns 0

Comment: I update my first html code to see exactly what is there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This jquery code can help you:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).next().prop("checked", true);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k5rkxkos/

**Update**

In pure Javascript (because you said that you are not expert in jquery ;) ), you can do:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
        document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k5rkxkos/1/

**Update**

This is the updated code according to your change:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    a[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = this.getAttribute("data");
        document.querySelector('input[data="' + id +'"]').checked = true;
    }
}
```

**Note**: You must add the input `name` attribute.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5rkxkos/2/)

Comment: I need this to be selected by Id i think, because there can be more than 10 options. and each image have their radio, thank you for you answer.

Comment: You can get the id by: `$(this).next()[0].id`

Comment: i found something like this:  onclick="document.getElementById('m1_2').checked=true;" but I'm not a jquery expert for that I post here

Comment: What if the next element ist no input ?

Comment: I get this error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: you must put `data-id` to your `a` like in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5rkxkos/1/)

Comment: i put my php there, maybe you need to see this

Comment: You `$_value->getOptionTypeId()` returns the `id` of the input?
If that is the case, just do: `<a data-id="<?php echo $_value->getOptionTypeId(); ?>"></a>` to add the  `data-id`

Comment: I don't know why but everything there return me 0 value

Comment: i think i found something to add data-id in the a tag,  but i have a little problem if you can tell me, I will add my entire code at my question, take a look at the last line there is a problem, may be with 
punctuation

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, can you tell me something? I solve to add Value to both: to a tag and to input field, so now I have the same data-id for both? can you modifiy your code for this? Thank you very much

Comment: The Code is up to date

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_1"  />
<label for="radio_1"><img src="image.jpg" id="radio_1" /></label>
<label for="radio_1">Radio - 1</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).next("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cuscbuk/

Comment: As there is a `onClick`-event on the radio-button it also could be a possible solution to trigger a click event an that.

Comment: Hi I edit my code can you take a look now? I have the same data="" attribute for both: for input and for image, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting an image name from a database on the Radio button.
In this example, I'm fetching images from a database and use them for the next SQL query. Or if you want to select the radio button by just click on the image then you need to set input id="value" and set lable for="value" (it means use the same value for input value and for label value) You can understand by reading code.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `img` FROM `table_name`";
$result_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = $result_sql -> fetch_assoc()) {
$img = $row['img']; ?>
    <input type="radio" name="img_name" value="<?= $img ?>" id="<?= $img ?>">
    <label for="<?= $img ?>"><img style="width:100px;" src='../upload/<?= $img ?>'></label>
<?php } ?>
```