# radio button as image with onclick to next fieldset

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button, fieldset

```
<a id="Choise" name="next" class="next Choise-button" value="Next" >
<input type="radio" name="designation" id="designation" />
<label for="designation"><img src="" alt="designation" />
<h2>designation</h2></label>
</a>
```

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$('#Choise input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise2 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise2 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise3 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise3 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise4 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise4 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise5 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise5 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise6 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise6 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise7 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise7 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise8 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise8 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#Choise9 input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#Choise9 label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 950px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 40px 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#msform select {
 text-align:left;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 30%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 400px;
 background: #00affe;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size:16px;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #00affe;
}
/*buttons2*/
#msform .choise-button {
 cursor: pointer;
}
#msform .choise-button:hover, #msform .choise-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #00affe;
 border: 10 solid;
 border-color: #FF0000;
}
#msform .Angaben {
 font-size:12px;
 text-align:left;
}
#msform .zustimmung {
 font-size:12px;
}
#msform .zustimmunglinks {
 font-size:12px;
 color:#00affe;
}
#msform .zustimmunglinks:hover, #msform .zustimmunglinks:active, #msform .zustimmunglinks:hover+label, #msform .zustimmunglinks:active+label {
 font-size:13px;
}

/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.hr { 
    width: 110%; 
 margin-left: -5%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.Abfragentext {
 border: 1px solid;
 width:300px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 margin: auto;
}
.fs-boldtitle {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sliderOutput {
 color: #00affe;
 font-weight: bold;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #00affe;
 color: white;
}
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #00affe;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
#usp.uspdiv {
 font-size:12px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20pt;
 background-color: #888888;
 width: 100%;
 hight:100%;
}
.usp-facts1 {
 font-size:13px;
 margin-top: 20pt;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px;
 padding-right:50px;
 margin-left:-40px;
 margin-bottom:-40px;
}
.usp-table {
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;

}
.usp-prima {
 font-size:18px;
 color:#00affe;
}

/*Seite eins Auswahlen*/
label:hover, label:active, input:hover+label, input:active+label {
 border: 3px solid;
 border-color: #00affe;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,175,254,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,175,254,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,175,254,0.5);
 transform: scale(1.05);
}

#Choise label {
 width: 400px;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#Choise2 label {
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
    }
#Choise2 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise2 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}


#Choise3 label {
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise3 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise3 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#Choise4 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-right:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise4 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise4 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}


#Choise5 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-right:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise5 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise5 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}


#Choise6 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise6 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise6 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Choise7 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise7 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise7 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Choise8 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise8 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise8 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Choise9 label {
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}
#Choise9 label img {
    padding: 3px;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
#Choise9 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*ragen Slider Etagen*/
input[type=range].etagenslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8.5px 0;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 15px rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(28, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: #484d4d;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid rgba(255, 30, 0, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #00afee;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -8.5px;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #7e8787;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 15px rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(28, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: #484d4d;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid rgba(255, 30, 0, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #00afee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #121313;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 15px rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(28, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #484d4d;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 15px rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(28, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
input[type=range].etagenslider::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid rgba(255, 30, 0, 0);
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #00afee;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3px;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #484d4d;
}
input[type=range].etagenslider:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #7e8787;
}
```

Hey, I am working on a contact form in which several steps are taken per .
the first step is that you can choose an image from six images. 
When you click on an image (which acts as hidden radio-button) then it allows to (are directed to) the next fieldset. 
This link prevent the radio buttons from being selected. do you have an idea how to activate the input with the link at the same time? I already tried it with an onclick, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I need the  to "group" the code, because otherwise, it dont work.

I'm looking forward to your ideas, thank you!

Edit: is it possible to say if `<a id="x1">` is klickes then select `<input type="radio" id="x1"` and how would the code look like? im not that good, sorry for that :(

Comment: Will you please add your css. Code as is works.

Comment: Success!
Made it.
Thanks to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122800/selecting-a-radio-button-when-clicking-an-image Thank you!