# How can I associate my HTML label with an ASP.Net radio button?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an HTML label that I have linked an image to, so that when you click the image, the image highlights and that selects the radio button (under the image). I am trying to turn the radio button into an ASP radio button so I can reference it in code behind, but cannot work out how to associate the labels.

I thought it may be because it's HTML to ASP, it might not work, so I have tried using an ASP label, but as far as I can tell, the label will not allow you to include an image within it.

This is how it looked working:

```
<div class="form-holder form-holder-2">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1" id="p1" value="p1">
        <label class="plan-icon plan-1-label" for="p1">
            <img src="images/frmMM1.png" alt="p1">
        </label>
    <div class="plan-total">
        <span class="plan-title">Managing your money</span>
        <p class="plan-text">Placeholder</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks now:

```
<div class="form-holder form-holder-2">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMM1" AssociatedControlID="rbMM1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="radio" GroupName="rbMM" Checked="true" />
        <label class="plan-icon plan-1-label" for="rbMM1" >
            <img src="images/frmMM1.png" alt="p1">
        </label>
    <div class="plan-total">
        <span class="plan-title">Managing your money</span>
        <p class="plan-text">Placeholder</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything looks the same initially when running the app, but the radio buttons aren't clickable (from the image). Is there a better way I can achieve the above?

Comment: jquery code can help you and answer is already given @[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122800/selecting-a-radio-button-when-clicking-an-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to use a different method to achieve this, by having hidden ASP radio buttons that are selected via javascript from the original buttons. If anyone stumbles across this in future, this is how I achieved it:

```
<div class="form-holder form-holder-2">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMM1" AssociatedControlID="rbMM1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="radio" GroupName="rbMM" Checked="true" />
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio1" id="p1" value="p1" onclick"clickRadioButton1()">
        <label class="plan-icon plan-1-label" for="rbMM1" >
            <img src="images/frmMM1.png" alt="p1">
        </label>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickRadioButton1() {
            document.getElementById("<%=rbMM1.ClientID %>").checked = true;
            }
        </script>
    <div class="plan-total">
        <span class="plan-title">Managing your money</span>
        <p class="plan-text">Placeholder</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `runat="server"` attribute to your label.

```
<label class="plan-icon plan-1-label" for="rbMM1" runat="server">
    <img src="images/frmMM1.png" alt="p1">
</label>
```

This way I am able to use the value of that label in code behind class. Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work - I tried adding runat="server" to the image source too, but that hasn't work either.

Comment: Well your answer shows you wanted to access ASP.NET label in JS. Maybe I misunderstood your question. From your question, I thought you wanted to access an HTML label in your code behind. Anyway, it's good you worked it out yourself.